# Falcor: avoid outdated client cache

Tags: caching, websocket, falcor

I'm considering to use [Falcor](http://netflix.github.io/falcor) in an app project I'm currently working on, I've started reading the docs but there's still one issue that is not entirely clear to me.

Let's make this example.

1. At time **zero** client **A** performs a request to a Falcor model, which in turns **retrieves** the needed data from a server `DataSource`, and stores it in the client's cache.
2. At time **one** the same server data is **changed** by operations performed by client **B**.
3. At time **two** client **A** performs the same request to the Falcor model, which finds a **cached** value and serves the now **outdated** data.

Is there any way to notifiy client **A** after time one that its Falcor cache for that data is outdated, and should instead perform a **new request** to the server `DataSource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use web sockets to send messages to the client. On the client you can call invalidate to manually invalidate the cache. You can also set an expires time on values to cause them to expire after a certain amount of time.